# add a UI Action in alfresco

Tags: user-interface, action, alfresco-share

i'm trying to add a ui action in alfresco so i first add it in alfresco web client and i succeded (i followed Jeff Potts tutorial) i want now to add the same UI action in alfresco share so i made a file  named share-config-custom.xml and i put it in the same folder as web-client-config-custom.xml but it dosen't work is there a problem ? 
the code of share-config-custom.xml

```
    <alfresco-config>
       <config  condition="DocLibActions">
               <actions>
                   <action id="web_site">
            <label>SomeCo</label>
            <href>any_Link</href>
            <image>/someco/images/icons/website.gif</image>
            <target>new</target>
        </action>
              </actions>
              <actionGroups>
              <actionGroup id="document-browse">
              <action index="400" id="web_site"/>
            </actionGroup>
              <actionGroup id="document-details">
            <action index="400" id="web_site"/>
             </actionGroup>
      </actionGroups>
      </config>
    </alfresco-config>
```

Is there a problem ?
Is there any good tutorial to do this one ?

Comment: what version of alfresco you run?

Comment: i'm using alfresco 4.2.f community

Answer (score 0):

At [this link](http://ecmarchitect.com/images/articles/alfresco-actions/actions-article-2ed.pdf) on page 23 you have detailed description how should share-config-custom.xml look like when adding custom action in UI. You need to know that things with Alfresco change quickly from version to version and info in this tutorial doesn't need to be 100% correct.

Comment: it's not working, share-config-custom.xml should be in the same folder as web-client-config-custom.xml no !  ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ok. You need to place share-config-custom.xml file under
/share/classes/alfresco/web-extension